# How to deserialize nested struct?

Tags: rust, serde-json

Assuming the following JSON should be read:

```rust
let json = r#"{
    "scjson": [
        { "StateMachine": { "id": "sm_1" } },
        { "StateMachine": { "id": "sm_2" } }
    ]
}"#;
```

In words: An array of StateMachine, with each StateMachine has a field "id" from type string.

How can I deserialize this with serde?
I tried:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct StateMachine {
    id: String,
}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct Scjson {
    scjson: Vec<StateMachine>,
}
```

But the ID is never deserialized.

In the end, I would like to parse:

```yaml
scjson:
  - StateMachine:
      id: "sm_1"
      states:
        - AtomicState:
            id: atomic_1
        - AtomicState:
            id: atomic_2
            transitions:
              - Transition: { event: "E1", executable_content: "asdf" }
        - ParallelState:
            InitialTransition: { }
        - CompoundState:
            id: compound_1
            initialTransition: { event: "E2", condition: "some condition" }
  - StateMachine:
      id: "sm_2"
      states:
        - FinalState:
            id: "asdf"
            onEntry: "17"
```

Comment: Is the format of the YAML fixed or are you defining it? The `StateMachine:` in yaml does not seem to achieve what you want it to in the latter case. Your Rust code assumes "`scjson` is a list of `{id: foo}` objects", but your YAML represents "`scjson` is a list of `{StateMachine: {id: foo}}`" objects.

Comment: @justinas I am defining it. Just switched it to json equivalent.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `StateMachine` key? The equivalent of the structure you defined in Rust would be `{"scjson": [{"id": "sm_1"}, {"id": "sm_2"}]}`

Comment: @justinas, ok I am confused. The idea is parse the json - and I am not capable of defining the equivalent Rust code.

Comment: I am trying to learn more about the structure of the JSON you're trying to parse. Can the list elements have some other types, e.g. `{"scjson": [{"StateMachine": {"id : "sm_1"}}, {"AnotherObject": {"foo": "bar"}}]}`? Depending on whether that's the case, I might recommend different solutions.

Comment: In this case, the list elements will all be StateMachine - but the next case, will have a list with different elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one layer of indirection. The `scjson` key contains a list of YAML dictionaries, where each dictionary has a single key `StateMachine`, and its value is yet another dictionary with one key `id`.

Here's the fixed version:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_yaml;

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct StateMachine {
    id: String,
}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct Scjson {
    scjson: Vec<ScjsonElement>,
}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct ScjsonElement {
    StateMachine: StateMachine,
}

fn main() {
    let message = r#"
scjson:
  - StateMachine:
      id: "sm_1"
  - StateMachine:
      id: "sm_2"
    "#;

    let result: Scjson = serde_yaml::from_str(message).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", result)
}
```

This is the straightforward solution, but it seems that whatever produces the YAML/JSON uses `StateMachine` and similar keys to encode the element type. If that is the case, then `enum` is the proper answer:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_yaml;

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct StateMachine {
    id: String,
}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct Scjson {
    scjson: Vec<ScjsonElement>,
}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub enum ScjsonElement {
    StateMachine(StateMachine),
}

fn main() {
    let message = r#"
scjson:
  - StateMachine:
      id: "sm_1"
  - StateMachine:
      id: "sm_2"
    "#;

    let result: Scjson = serde_yaml::from_str(message).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", result)
}
```

Comment: just to be sure: this has nothing to do with yaml != json?
And why do I need the indirection?

Comment: No, both YAML and JSON examples are equivalent. Please try to read my comments and answer again: each element of the `scjson` list is of form `{"StateMachine": {"id": "some_value"}}`. Your initial code assumes that the form of these list elements is simply `{"id": "some_value"}`

Comment: The initial code was wrong. I want to be explicit, hence the word StateMachine in the yaml file.

Comment: That's why I initially asked whether you are designing your own JSON file, or have to parse something that you can not change the structure of. JSON/YAML does not really do "type information", but if you want to be explicit, and also support e.g. several different "types" of elements in a single list, the enum option is the best - it is exactly what you need to then implement `AtomicState`, `ParallelState`, etc.